wake on magic packet - keep wifi card active during sleep
I have a PC that I connect to remotely, so I set up wake on magic packet (not wake on lan - I send a magic packet via the wireless card + router to the PC when it's sleeping - I dont shut it down completely) so I can wake it from sleep when I want to use it.
This is currently working well.
The problem is, when the PC sleeps for a long time (longer than an hour or so), wake on magic packet stops working. From my research and limited understanding of networking, it seems like the router's ARP table clears out the entry for the PC, so the magic packet no longer reaches the PC.
I was thinking of not allowing my computer to turn off the wireless card so it stays connected to the router by going to device manager and turning OFF the following setting:
Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power
but the problem is, when I do that, the other 2 settings under it get greyed out:
Allow this device to wake the computer
and
Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer
And when I do this, wake on magic packet stops working completely.
What is a workaround for this?
I'd like the wireless device to continue working (so the router doesnt clear it from the ARP table) so that I can continue using wake on magic packet even if the PC has been sleeping for a long time.
